# AWS DMS: Replication Instance Fails to Connect to Kinesis Target Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-programming, amazon-kinesis, aws-dms

I am working on setting up an AWS CloudFormation stack to deploy a database using Aurora Postgres Serverless V2, some network resources, a Jumpbox, and some AWS DMS resources to use real-time CDC as trigger for downstream services.

The key components of the setup include:

- Initiation of an Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL database within a Virtual
  Private Cloud (VPC).
- Establishing a specific security group for the Aurora PostgreSQL
  database. This group will be configured to accept connections solely
  from distinct security groups.
- Configuring a second security group, defined for database access,
  that's authorized to interact with the PostgreSQL database. This
  security group will be granted outbound traffic permissions to the
  internet.
- Establishing network communication between the resources residing in
  the VPC and the internet with NAT gateways and necessary routing rules.
- Setting up a public subnet along with necessary configuration within
  the VPC to enable local database connection via a Jumpbox.
- Implementing AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) resources to enable
  real-time Change Data Capture (CDC) from the Aurora PostgreSQL
  database to an Amazon Kinesis Data Stream.

What I am having issues with is the last point in the list: so far, I have correctly set up my replication instance to connect succesfully to my Aurora Postgres DB (Source Endpoint), though, I am not able to connect my replication to Kinesis Data Stream (Target Endpoint).

Following the official AWS documentation found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_VPC_Endpoints.html), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/security-iam.html#CHAP_Security.APIRole), and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dms-endpoint-kinesissettings.html#cfn-dms-endpoint-kinesissettings-serviceaccessrolearn) I've also set up the VPC endpoints for my Kinesis and DMS, as well as created the roles `dms-vpc-role` and `dms-cloudwatch-logs-role` with policy, respecitvely, `AmazonDMSVPCManagementRole` and `AmazonDMSCloudWatchLogsRole`.

The connection from my replication instance to my Kinesis Data Stream fails with the error: `Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to connect to database.`

I am not a network engineer, therefore there might be some details I am missing in my setup and that would fix the replication instance to  Kinesis Data Stream connection issue. Seeking help to identify these issues.

Below, you will find my CloudFormation setup:

```yaml
Parameters:
  StackStage:
    Description: The stage/environment
    Type: String
    Default: ${opt:stage}

Resources:
  MyVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyVPC

  MyInternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyInternetGateway

  MyVPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref MyInternetGateway

  MyPrivateSubnet1a:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      CidrBlock: "10.0.1.0/24"
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyPrivateSubnet1a

  MyPrivateSubnet1b:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      CidrBlock: "10.0.2.0/24"
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs '' ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyPrivateSubnet1b

  MyDBAccessSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: MyDBAccessSecurityGroup
      GroupDescription: Security Group for My DB Access
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: '-1'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyDBAccessSecurityGroup

  MyDBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: MyDBSecurityGroup
      GroupDescription: Security Group for MyDB
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 5432
          ToPort: 5432
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt MyDBAccessSecurityGroup.GroupId
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 5432
          ToPort: 5432
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt MyJumpBoxSecurityGroup.GroupId
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyDBSecurityGroup

  MyNATGateway1aEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  MyNATGateway1bEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  MyNATGateway1a:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt MyNATGateway1aEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1a

  MyNATGateway1b:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt MyNATGateway1bEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1b

  MyRouteTable1a:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyRouteTable1a

  MyRouteTable1b:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyRouteTable1b

  MyDefaultRouteSubnet1a:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: MyNATGateway1a
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable1a
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref MyNATGateway1a

  MyDefaultRouteSubnet1b:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: MyNATGateway1b
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable1b
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref MyNATGateway1b

  MyPrivateSubnet1aRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1a
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable1a

  MyPrivateSubnet1bRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1b
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyRouteTable1b

  MyJumpBoxSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: MyJumpBoxSecurityGroup
      GroupDescription: Security Group for My Jump Box
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: '-1'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyJumpBoxSecurityGroup

  MyPublicSubnet1a:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      CidrBlock: "10.0.3.0/24"
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyPublicSubnet1a

  MyPublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyPublicRouteTable

  MyDefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: MyVPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyPublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref MyInternetGateway

  MyPublicSubnet1aRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref MyPublicSubnet1a
      RouteTableId: !Ref MyPublicRouteTable

  MyJumpboxKeyPair:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair
    Properties:
      KeyName: MyJumpBoxKeyPair
      KeyFormat: pem
      KeyType: rsa
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyJumpBoxKeyPair

  MyJumpBoxInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    DependsOn: MyJumpboxKeyPair
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0fb2f0b847d44d4f0
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: !Ref MyJumpboxKeyPair
      SubnetId: !Ref MyPublicSubnet1a
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref MyJumpBoxSecurityGroup
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyJumpBoxInstance

  MyDBSecret:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '${StackStage}/MyDBSecret'
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "admin"}'
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
        PasswordLength: 32
        ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\\:;+%=.,?<>{}[]()~`#$^&*|'

  MyDBCluster:
    DependsOn: MyDBSecret                      
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties:
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      Port: 5432
      ServerlessV2ScalingConfiguration:
        MinCapacity: 1
        MaxCapacity: 4
      MasterUsername: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:${MyDBSecret}::username}}'
      MasterUserPassword: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:${MyDBSecret}::password}}'
      DBClusterIdentifier: My-db-cluster
      DatabaseName: database
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 7
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref MyDBSubnetGroup
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt MyDBSecurityGroup.GroupId
      StorageEncrypted: true
      KmsKeyId: "alias/aws/rds"
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyDBCluster

  MyDBInstance1:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      DBInstanceClass: db.serverless
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref MyDBCluster
      DBInstanceIdentifier: My-instance-1
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyDBInstance1

  MyDBSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupName: MyDBSubnetGroup
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: Subnet group for MyDBCluster
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1a
        - !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1b
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyDBSubnetGroup

 MyDMSVpcEndpoint:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      ServiceName: !Sub 'com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.dms'
      VpcEndpointType: 'Interface'
      PrivateDnsEnabled: true
      SubnetIds: 
        - !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1a
        - !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1b
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !GetAtt MyDBAccessSecurityGroup.GroupId

  MyKinesisVPCEndpoint:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref MyVPC
      ServiceName: !Sub 'com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.kinesis-streams'
      VpcEndpointType: 'Interface'
      PrivateDnsEnabled: true
      SubnetIds: 
        - !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1a
        - !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1b
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !GetAtt MyDBAccessSecurityGroup.GroupId

  MyReplicationSubnetGroup:
    Type: "AWS::DMS::ReplicationSubnetGroup"
    Properties: 
      ReplicationSubnetGroupIdentifier: MyReplicationSubnetGroup
      ReplicationSubnetGroupDescription: 'Subnet group for DMS Replication'
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1a
        - !Ref MyPrivateSubnet1b

  MyReplicationInstance:
    Type: 'AWS::DMS::ReplicationInstance'
    Properties: 
      ReplicationInstanceIdentifier: 'MyReplicationInstance'
      ReplicationInstanceClass: 'dms.t2.micro'
      AllocatedStorage: 5
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      VpcSecurityGroupIds: 
        - !GetAtt MyDBAccessSecurityGroup.GroupId
      ReplicationSubnetGroupIdentifier: !Ref MyReplicationSubnetGroup
      MultiAZ: false
      EngineVersion: '3.5.1'
      PubliclyAccessible: false
      AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: true

  MyDMSSourceEndpoint:
    Type: 'AWS::DMS::Endpoint'
    DependsOn: MyDBSecret
    Properties: 
      EndpointIdentifier: 'MyDMSSourceEndpoint'
      EndpointType: 'source'
      EngineName: aurora-postgresql
      DatabaseName: database
      Username: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:${MyDBSecret}::username}}'
      Password: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:${MyDBSecret}::password}}'
      ServerName: !GetAtt MyDBCluster.Endpoint.Address
      Port: 5432

  MyKinesisStream:
    Type: 'AWS::Kinesis::Stream'
    Properties: 
      Name: 'MyKinesisStream'
      ShardCount: 1

  MyDMSTargetEndpoint:
    Type: 'AWS::DMS::Endpoint'
    DependsOn: MyDMSVpcEndpoint
    Properties:
      EndpointIdentifier: 'MyDMSTargetEndpoint'
      EndpointType: 'target'
      EngineName: 'kinesis'
      KinesisSettings:
        MessageFormat: 'json'
        StreamArn: !GetAtt MyKinesisStream.Arn
        ServiceAccessRoleArn: !GetAtt MyDMSTargetAccessRole.Arn

  MyDMSTargetAccessRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: 'MyDMSTargetAccessRole'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - 'dms.amazonaws.com'
          Action: 
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: 'DMSAccessPolicy'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:

            - Effect: Allow
              Action: 
              - 'kinesis:*'
              Resource: '*'

            - Effect: Allow
              Action: iam:PassRole
              Resource: "*"

      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonDMSVPCManagementRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonDMSCloudWatchLogsRole
```

Thank you for your time, and any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue when using a Kinesis target endpoint. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: yes. My Nat Gateway setup was wrong. The subnet for the Nat gateway has to be the public subnet, not the private one. That solved the issue.